# Hashmap with key as String and value as List

Tags: java, list, hashmap, initialization

For each student , there is a name , subject list along with marks .
i need to take input for student name and his marks and then return the top 3 students based on marks.
I tried using Hashmap and a list to get the marks. After taking the marks of 1st student in list i am clearing everything from the list and taking the input again. But this is changing the data for the first student also . I am not sure what i am doing wrong here?

````
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> marks=new ArrayList<>();
    //1st student detail
        marks.add(12);
        marks.add(10);
        marks.add(15);
        map.put("Rakesh",marks);
        System.out.println(map);
    //Reset the marks List
        marks.clear();
    //2nd student detail
        marks.add(9);
        marks.add(8);
        marks.add(15);
        map.put("Ashwin",marks);
        System.out.println(map); 
   //Reset the marks List
        marks.clear()     
    //3rd student detail
        marks.add(7);
        marks.add(11);
        marks.add(8);
        map.put("Rahul",marks);
        System.out.println(map);```
````

Comment: You are saving the **reference** to the `arraylist` marks in the map, so all map values are pointing to the same `arraylist`. Create a different arraylist for every student.

Comment: instead of "clearing everything from the list" create a  new list instance (one for each student)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding multiple entries to the `HashMap` with the *same* object reference.  Instead of the `HashMap` making a copy of what you `put` into it, it stores only the reference.  All your keys point to the same `marks` list, so only the list entries after the last `clear` show up.

```
Rakesh ----> [7, 11, 8]
Ashwin -/ /
Rahul  --/
```

Instead, create new `ArrayList`s for each key, so each key can reference a unique `ArrayList` object.

Answer (score 1):

You only create one `List`, and you keep clearing it.

Get rid of `clear()`, and create a new list for each student:

```java
    ...
//1st student detail
    marks.add(12);
    marks.add(10);
    marks.add(15);
    map.put("Rakesh",marks);
    System.out.println(map);
// Create a new marks list:
    marks = new ArrayList<>();
// 2nd student detail
    marks.add(9);
    marks.add(8);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how Object reference works in Java. If you replace marks.clear() with marks = new ArrayList<>() then you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You're repeatedly adding to and clearing the same list.

I would do it like this.

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();

map.computeIfAbsent("Rakesh", v->new ArrayList<>()).addAll(List.of(12,10,15));
map.computeIfAbsent("Ashwin", v->new ArrayList<>()).addAll(List.of(9,8,15));
map.computeIfAbsent("Rahul", v->new ArrayList<>()).addAll(List.of(7,11,8));
```

- [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) will create and return an `ArrayList` or return the existing one. Then you can just add the values to the returned list.
- Later on you can update the `list` using the same construct and it will either add the value/values to an existing person, or create a new map entry and add it there.

```
map.entrySet().foreach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Rahul=[7, 11, 8]
Ashwin=[9, 8, 15]
Rakesh=[12, 10, 15]
```

If you want to preserve the order entries were added to the Map use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). If you want the map to be sorted based on the Key (person) use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the **reference** to the `arraylist` *marks* in the `map`, so all `map` values are pointing to the same `arraylist`. Create a different `arraylist` for every student.
You can use something like this:

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> marks=new ArrayList<>();
    //1st student detail
        marks.add(12);
        marks.add(10);
        marks.add(15);
        map.put("Rakesh", new ArrayList<Integer>(marks));
        System.out.println(map);
    //Reset the marks List
        marks.clear();
    //2nd student detail
        marks.add(9);
        marks.add(8);
        marks.add(15);
        map.put("Ashwin",new ArrayList<Integer>(marks));
        System.out.println(map); 
   //Reset the marks List
        marks.clear()     
    //3rd student detail
        marks.add(7);
        marks.add(11);
        marks.add(8);
        map.put("Rahul",new ArrayList<Integer>(marks));
        System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. Create List and inject each element with Arrays.asList.

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> marks;
    //1st student detail
    marks = Arrays.asList(12,10,15);
    map.put("Rakesh",marks);
    System.out.println(map);
    //2nd student detail
    marks= Arrays.asList(9,8,15);
    map.put("Ashwin",marks);
    System.out.println(map);
    //3rd student detail
    marks= Arrays.asList(7,11,8);
    map.put("Rahul",marks);
    System.out.println(map);
```